# log_bin enabled but Show binary logs is still throwing an error

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> show variables like '%log_bin';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| log_bin       | ON    |
| sql_log_bin   | ON    |
+---------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show binary logs;
ERROR 1381 (HY000): You are not using binary logging
mysql>
```

Surprisingly, server was running fine and started acting like this, no restart or variable changes were made.

Comment: Did your server ran out of disk space when mysql server was running ?

Comment: Please post TEXT results of  A) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE "%bin%"; and B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE "uptime";  Thank you.

Comment: No issues with disk space.

Comment: Issue is due to binlog_error_action variable being set to IGNORE _ERROR.

Comment: Are you aware of the fix and why does this happen in the first place?

Comment: Please consider posting TEXT results of A) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE "%bin%"; and B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE "uptime"; Thank you.

Comment: | binlog_cache_size                          | 32768                                      |
| binlog_checksum                            | CRC32                                      |
| binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates    | OFF                                        |
| binlog_error_action                        | IGNORE_ERROR                               |
| binlog_format                              | ROW                                        |

Comment: binlog_group_commit_sync_delay             | 0   |
| binlog_group_commit_sync_no_delay_count    | 0   |
| binlog_gtid_simple_recovery                | ON   |
| binlog_max_flush_queue_time                | 0  |
| binlog_order_commits  | ON |
| binlog_row_image | FULL  
| binlog_rows_query_log_events  | OFF   |
| binlog_stmt_cache_size  | 32768    |
| binlog_transaction_dependency_history_size | 25000  |
| binlog_transaction_dependency_tracking  | COMMIT_ORDER |
| innodb_api_enable_binlog  | OFF   |
| innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog  | OFF   |
| log_bin  | ON      |

Comment: mysql> SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE "uptime";
+---------------+--------+
| Variable_name | Value  |
+---------------+--------+
| Uptime        | 237549 |
+---------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)